# Android BouncyCastle (SpongyCastle) HTTPS POST request

Tags: android, bouncycastle, tls1.2, spongycastle

I am trying to login to my TLS1.2 server on an old Android device running Jellybean 4.1.2, with the BouncyCastle (SpongyCastle) library, but it doesn't work. That version of Android does not have TLS enabled by default, so I needed the 3rd party lib to use it.

There are two problems.
1. I get a HTTP 302 instead of a JSON response.
2. I don't know how to send a JSON payload (for other endpoints I'll be using

With the HTTP 302, I get the following response:

```
Result: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=83C535625CDEF9DEC3D7890F1A9C86B0; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: https://www.google.com/login/auth                                                               Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2018 15:32:19 GMT
Via: 1.1 google
Set-Cookie: GCLB=CMfzgbfeh7bLpwE; path=/; HttpOnly
Alt-Svc: clear
Connection: close
```

So it seems its trying to redirect to some sort of Google login, which is weird.

Also, with number 2 above, where I'm trying to send a payload, do I just add another `output.write(myJSONPayload);` or do I have to do something else?

My code is as follows:

```
{
    java.security.SecureRandom secureRandom = new java.security.SecureRandom();
    Socket socket = new Socket("www.myserver.com", 443);

    TlsClientProtocol protocol = new TlsClientProtocol(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream(), secureRandom);
    DefaultTlsClient client = new DefaultTlsClient() {
        public TlsAuthentication getAuthentication() throws IOException {
            TlsAuthentication auth = new TlsAuthentication() {
                // Capture the server certificate information!
                public void notifyServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate) throws IOException {
                }

                public TlsCredentials getClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest) throws IOException {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            return auth;
        }
    };
    protocol.connect(client);

    java.io.OutputStream output = protocol.getOutputStream();
    output.write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));

    //Get auth with my own class to generate base 64 encoding
    output.write(("Authorization: " + BasicAuthentication.getAuthenticationHeader("myuser", "mypass")).getBytes());

    output.write("Host: www.myserver.com/logon\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    output.write("Connection: close\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); // So the server will close socket immediately.
    output.write("\r\n".getBytes("UTF-8")); // HTTP1.1 requirement: last line must be empty line.
    output.flush();

    java.io.InputStream input = protocol.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "--> " + line);
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (TlsNoCloseNotifyException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "End of stream");
    }

    String result = sb.toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "Result: " + result);
}
```

Another question, do I have the correct HOST specified? Am I right to have the base URL in the `Socket`, and the full URL in the `OutputStream`?

Comment: Why aren't you using the HTTP classes?

Comment: My server is TLS1.2 only. From Android Jellybean to KitKat, TLS1.2 was not enabled by default. I tried enabling it while using normal HTTP classes (overriding SSLFactory etc) but I couldn't get it to work. I tried bouncycastle and it seemed to work first time so I just need to get bouncycastle working with my existing code.

Comment: By "HTTP Classes" I assume you mean the built in Android `HTTPSURLConnection` class etc?

Comment: Recent versions of BouncyCastle include a JSSE provider ("BCJSSE"). I believe SpongyCastle now also repackages that (as "SCJSSE") - in the tls module. In principle, you could just register this alternate JSSE provider ahead of the default one, and HttpsURLConnection should make use of it.

Comment: @PeterDettman do you mean I just use standard Android code, with this at the start: `Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);` ?

Comment: Yes, except it's a separate provider class from the normal crypto one - org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider (and it's in a separate jar - tls).

Comment: I tried that and got a weird error: `IllegalArgumentException: 'protocols' cannot be null, or contain unsupported protocols`. I debugged it and `ProvSSLSocketWrap.setEnabledProtocols()` is being called twice. The first time with `TLSv1.2` and the second time with `SSL3`, which throws the error. So I can't see why it's being called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to add this method to my custom SSLSocketFactory:

```
private static void setupSecurityForTLS() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Adding new security provider");
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 1);
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 2);
    }
}
```

and call it BEFORE I initialise the socket.

You can also add the 2 lines to a static initialiser at the top of the class, eg:

```
static {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 1);
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 2);
}
```